# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI in http package (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I am fetching the data by using the `http` package library and the url i am using is `$baseURL/restaurant_branches/1?lang=en`. In postman it is working fine but in app side it is showing me an error "======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI". I even try with `http:/` and `http://` but still doesn't work. I don't understand what is the issue, is it in http package bug because it was working fine before.

Comment: It would help to clarify the question if you would post a snippet of the code that produces the error. Understanding the value of $baseURL is the key to answering the problem.

Comment: @CurtEckhart $baseURL is "http://api.tuxedo.dev.dafa.sa:3000".

Comment: You'll need to post some code if you want an anwer.

Comment: @CurtEckhart This is some code when i hit this api and displays error in console `var response = await http
        .get(Uri.parse(
            '$baseURL/restaurant_branches/1?lang=en');`

Comment: Kindly edit your original question and post the short passage of code that creates and assigns the baseURL variable along with the call. Single lines of code aren't that helpful to help you figure this out.